# Evolution will not send mail with attachments

Tags: evolution

I have been using Evolution for years. After updating to 15:04 malis with an attachment do not go to the receiver but show as sent in "sent box". Also the search function in the in-box does not work but it does in all the other boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the as below

1. Go to Edit
2. Go to `Preferences`
3. Select the your email account (xxx@xxx.com) & click `edit`
4. Click button `Sending Email`
5. Check Mark `Server Requires Authentication`
6. Select `Encryption Method` (STARTTLS after connecting)
7. Authentication Type: `Login`
8. Click OK button

During this process or after pressing ok a popup windows appears in which you have to give password of your email id thats all.

It worked with me hope will work for you also. Have a nice day

Regards,
Umair Ahmed

Comment: Thanks Umair, unfortunately it didn't work. Regards Dick

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a bug in the evolution 3.12.11 package used in Ubuntu 15.04. You may want to visit the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1460047 and mark that it affects you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching to port 587 and setting  "Authentication Required". Added "Username" and checked for supported types.